# Differences among various index theories in critical point theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, critical-point-theory

Index theories help characterize critical points of functionals having certain symmetries. What are the differences (regarding problems they can be applied to) between for example these ones?

- the classical symmetric Mountain Pass theorem
- the cohomological index
- the genus
- the $S^1$ index